# passing javascript value to another page

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to passing javascript variable value to another page and retrieve here into a php variable

Using function i made a pop up to appear and store it to a java script variable  so now how do i pass it another page and i do have some text box values but i get this ,i use action and give page name in it.I need both text box value and prompt value in another page.

Answer (score 1):

Please understand JavaScript is ran on the client machine, and PHP on the server.

HTTP is stateless.

Comment: I know it alex.How to get my js var value in nxt page.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AJAX.
Are you familiar with AJAX?

Comment: Please consider learning AJAX. You would need to learn this anyway if you want to develop Web Applications.

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript to dynamically add hidden form fields into your form and set the value (alternatively just create the hidden fields in the php output with no value and just use JS to set it).

Comment: @nick: <input type="hidden" value="document.write(a);" > but this is not working

Comment: @deree There is no JavaScript there. Use the `value` property of the `input` element.

Comment: @alex: What is document.write called as?I have used it in value only.Pls see my script correctly

Comment: Right, first of all you need to give your hidden field a name/ID so that your JS can reference it.  Then you need to just set that value in the JS - document.getElementById(hiddenElementID).value = whateverYouWantItToBe

Comment: @Nick: Should i use u r script in next page or in this page only

Comment: You make the hidden field on the first page and that's where the JS will run.  Then on the second page, the value of the hidden field will be available to PHP in the parameters (the same as the values of your text boxes).  Does that make sense?

Comment: @nick:<input type="hidden" name="h" value="javascript:document.getElementByName(h).value =ans;">here ans has got value through prompt and stored it is a js variab name.next page what shoul i do?

Comment: The JS doesn't go in the value attribute.  I'm not sure what you're actually doing but you should have that bit of JS code trigger when either the form is submitted or something else happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jQuery you can call something like:

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" } );
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: I wrote a function it get i/p from prompt and stores it in a variable,now need to pass this value to next page.

Answer (score 0):

Using JS you can put a variable into cookie:

```
document.cookie = 'var1=VALUE1'
```

Then read it on the other page.

Or you can append `#var1=value1` to URL, then read it on the other page using

```
top.location.hash
```